# Ruby method using class and instances

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a method that returns `"Title was written by author"`, where `title` and `author` are variables. I think I'm close, but I'm not sure what to add at this point.

```
class Book
  def set_title_and_author=(title, author)
    @title = title
    @author = author
  end
  def set_title_and_author
    "#{@title} was written by #{@author}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Just as a comment that may help you google about it, this feature is called string interpolation.

Comment: I have a question: for `Book.new.set_title_and_author=("title", "author")`, why it doesn't work?

Comment: It appears that someone agrees with you that you are "close". :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on @orde's answer, I would also use the wonderful `#attr_accessor` method to automatically create setters and getters for `title` and `author`.

```
class Book
  # create the setter and getter methods
  attr_accessor :title, :author

  # create an optional initializer
  def initialize(title = nil, author = nil)
    @title = title
    @author = author
  end

  def print_title_and_author
    puts "#{@title} was written by #{@author}"
  end
end

book = Book.new("Blood Meridian", "Cormac McCarthy")
book.print_title_and_author
# => Blood Meridian was written by Cormac McCarthy

book.title = "Blue moon"
book.print_title_and_author
# => Blue moon was written by Cormac McCarthy
```

Creating different setters and getters for different attributes is preferred.

You can also create chain-setters, which is becoming a trend now, so you can set many attributes with one line of code. you do this by returning `self` after performing the task (setting the attribute):

```
# Reopen the class to add methods,
# the old code is still being used!
class Book
  def set_title title
    @title = title
    self
  end
  def set_author author
    @author = author
    self
  end
  def to_s
    "#{@title} was written by #{@author}"
  end
end

#chain set attributes
book.set_title('My New Title').set_author('Me')
#print the output - notice the #to_s is implied
puts book
# => My New Title was written by Me
```

You don't need the initializer, but please notice that the current `#print_title_and_author` and `#to_s` methods produce a funny output if the attributes aren't set.

We can change that with an `if` statement (actually, I will use `unless`). Le't open the class again and re-define these methods:

```
# Reopen the class to add methods,
# the old code is still being used!
class Book

  def to_s
    return "author or title missing!" unless @author && @title
    "#{@title} was written by #{@author}"
  end

  def print_title_and_author
    puts self.to_s #DRY code - do not repeat yourself.
  end

end

new_book = Book.new
puts new_book
# => author or title missing!
```

I think this is better.

Good Luck, and welcome to Ruby!

Comment: Thanks! is initialize() essential here or can that be replaced?

Comment: You can remove it. It's not essential. It's more of a style...still, please notice that without setting the values you get this funny string: `" was written by "`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that methods ending in `=` are unusual in that they must have a single argument, and you are passing two (`title` and `author`). (Also, Ruby allows you to insert spaces before `=`; e.g., `set_title_and_author   = arg`.)

I can suggest four ways you might fix that:

- make the argument the array `[title, author]` (i.e., a single value);
- change the name of the method to `set_title_and_author` (and rename the getter);
- replace the method `set_title_and_author=` with two setters, `title=` and `author=`, which you can write out explicitly or have Ruby do it for you by executing the method `attr_writer :title, :author` or `attr_accessor :title, :author`; or
- use the `initialize` method as the setter.

**First way**

```
class Book
  def title_and_author=(arr)
    @title, @author = arr
  end
  def title_and_author
    "#{@title} was written by #{@author}"
  end
end

b = Book.new
  #=> #<Book:0x007f91e414eb78> 
b.title_and_author=(["Moby Dick", "Herman Melville"])
  #=> ["Moby Dick", "Herman Melville"] 
b.title_and_author
  #=> "Moby Dick was written by Herman Melville"
```

Notice that I renamed your methods by dropping `set_`. `set` is not needed in the first case and is misleading in the second, where `get` would be more appropriate, but again, is not needed.

**Second way**

```
class Book
  def set_title_and_author(title, author)
    @title = title
    @author = author
  end
  def title_and_author
    "#{@title} was written by #{@author}"
  end
end
b = Book.new
b.set_title_and_author("Moby Dick", "Herman Melville")
b.title_and_author
  #=> "Moby Dick was written by Herman Melville"
```

Notice that I've changed the name of the first method back to `set_title_and_author`. It can't have the same name as the getter method and, without the `=` on the end, the name needs modification to suggest what it does.

I prefer this to the "second way" (making the argument an array).

**Third way**

```
class Book
  attr_writer :title, :author
  def title_and_author
    "#{@title} was written by #{@author}"
  end
end
b = Book.new
b.title  = "Moby Dick"
b.author = "Herman Melville"
b.title_and_author
  #=> "Moby Dick was written by Herman Melville"
```

**Fourth way**

```
class Book
  def initialize(title, author)
    @title = title
    @author = author
  end
  def title_and_author
    "#{@title} was written by #{@author}"
  end
end
b = Book.new("Moby Dick", "Herman Melville")
b.title_and_author
  #=> "Moby Dick was written by Herman Melville"
```

This is a very common way of setting instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a setter method to assign the title and author, you should use the `initialize` method to set up an object's initial state:

```
class Book
  def initialize(title, author)
    @title = title
    @author = author
  end

  def print_title_and_author
    puts "#{@title} was written by #{@author}"
  end
end

book = Book.new("Blood Meridian", "Cormac McCarthy")
book.print_title_and_author
#=> Blood Meridian was written by Cormac McCarthy
```

Comment: @DavidHoelzer, Me too. There's a good way to fix that, though.  I think the accepted answer is too big of a jump from the op's code--and the setter/getter example contains code that I would consider bad practice. This answer is more of a baby step.